# Set an attribute type without setting _type in ElasticSearch with Tire

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

The document I want to index has a property with name `type`. When I use tire to store it, for instance:

```
Tire.index 'mydocuments' do
   delete
   create
   store :name => name, :type => 'pdf'
   refresh
end
```

Then this document is indexes with `_type = pdf` , hence I can access it with `http://localhost:9200/mydocuments/pdf/id`.

But how can I change this, that the type is  `mydocument` (singular) and not copied from my actual `type` property which comes from the document source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a `document_type` method for your object, or use a `_type` property for a Hash; see https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/lib/tire/index.rb#L456-L459